# Unable to compile PETSc programs in visual Studio 2019 after linking libraries

Tags: visual-studio, linker, visual-studio-2019, libraries, petsc

I am trying to compile a simple PETSc program (Which works when compiled in Cygwin) in Visual Studio 2019. But I am unable to compile it in VS2019 even after linking all the necessary library files. I have given below the options I have used in VS2019 for compiling petsc program. I see that the compiler is not able to identify the Petsc variables which leads me to believe that I have not done the library linking part properly.

**My guide for linking the files is from compiling the program in cygwin using the following command (compiles and run perfectly):**

```
/home/snarayanan1/petsc-release/lib/petsc/bin/win32fe/win32fe.exe ifort -MT -O3 -fpp -I/home/snarayanan1/petsc-release/include -I/home/snarayanan1/petsc-release/arch-ci-mswin-opt-impi/include -I/cygdrive/c/PROGRA~2/Intel/oneAPI/mpi/2021.5.0/include  petsc_solver.F90 Test_petsc.F90 -L/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/home/snarayanan1/petsc-release/arch-ci-mswin-opt-impi/lib -L/cygdrive/c/PROGRA~2/Intel/oneAPI/mkl/2022.0.0/lib/intel64 -lpetsc mkl_intel_lp64_dll.lib mkl_sequential_dll.lib mkl_core_dll.lib /cygdrive/c/PROGRA~2/Intel/oneAPI/mpi/2021.5.0/lib/release/impi.lib Gdi32.lib User32.lib Advapi32.lib Kernel32.lib Ws2_32.lib -o Test_petsc
```

**Fortran -> General -> Additional Include Directories:**

```
C:/cygwin64/home/snarayanan1/petsc-release/include; C:/cygwin64/home/snarayanan1/petsc-release/arch-ci-mswin-opt-impi/include; C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/oneAPI/mpi/2021.5.0/include
```

**Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories:**

```
C:/cygwin64/home/snarayanan1/petsc-release/arch-ci-mswin-opt-impi/lib; C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/oneAPI/mkl/2022.0.0/lib/intel64; C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/oneAPI/mpi/2021.5.0/lib/release
```

**Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies:**

```
libpetsc.lib mkl_intel_lp64_dll.lib mkl_sequential_dll.lib mkl_core_dll.lib C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/oneAPI/mpi/2021.5.0/lib/release/impi.lib Gdi32.lib User32.lib Advapi32.lib Kernel32.lib Ws2_32.lib
```

[This image shows the errors I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAYsQ.png)

Can someone let me know where I am going wrong (or) direct me to documentation that talks about linking PETSc to visual Studio in detail?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configurations that you have done look fine to me. The issue you ran into arises from other places.

Try

Fortran Tab:
•   Preprocessor | Preprocess source files | Yes